# How do you rerun "tox" on python file changes?

Tags: python, testing, tox

I have a tox configuration that runs all my tests, pep8 checks, and coverage checks. I run tox manually pretty much every time I save changes to my code. Tox runs the tests and coverage reports via "nosetests."

How do I make the re-running of tox happen automatically when changes are saved to python files anywhere within the directory structure beneath my tox.ini file?

Comment: You would need a background (daemon) process for this that polled the directories.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin - Thanks for the response. I knew that. What I'm asking is what daemon processes and configurations have people actually had success with, specifically with Python/tox if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try "tdaemon" like this:

```
$ tdaemon.py --test-program=tox
```